# AWS::CloudFormation::Init with Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

What is the equivalent of [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) with Azure Resource Manager template for [virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.Compute/2019-03-01/virtualMachines#SshPublicKey)? I would like to initialize the virtual machine by creating some files with specific content, and then run a few scripts. Is my only option using a long script in `customData` that creates those files and scripts? Or is there something better like `cfn-init` on AWS?

I would like to be able to define an object in my Azure template that can then be used during the initialization of the virtual machine to install a few packages, write a few files, and run a few scripts. In AWS I can use this with `cfn-init`:

```
        "Metadata" : {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "config" : {
                    "packages" : {
                        "apt" : {
                            "wget" : []
                        }
                    },
                    "files" : {
                        "/etc/some_file" : {
                            "content" : "some content"
                        }
                    },
                    "commands" : {
                        "foo": {
                            "command" : "echo hello world"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

The only option I could find so far is `customData` which requires me to write one big script like:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

sudo apt install wget

cat <<EOF > /etc/some_file
some content
EOF

echo hello world
```

This kind of scripts is hard to maintain. And if the files I want to write are binary, I need to add some hacks like base64.

Is there a better option I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

We can use custom script extension in ARM Templates to run script at startup

[Custom Script Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux)

Another option we can use is use of terraform as mentioned [here](http://teknews.cloud/bootstrapping-azure-vms-with-terraform/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to define the files content inside the template itself for the custom script extension?

Answer (score 0):

A few links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/using-cloud-init
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-data-and-cloud-init-on-windows-azure/
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-customdata

Custom script extension is also good...